# Trigger Dataflow job upon receiving of a PubSub notification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have wrote a Dataflow pipeline with Apache Beam, to give you a basic idea of the code:

```
Job= (
    p
    |"cretae">>beam.Create(["message"])
    |"job 1" >> beam.ParDo(dofn1())
    |"job 2" >> beam.ParDo(dofn2())
    |"job 3" >> beam.ParDo(dofn3())
    )
```

Currently, I am triggering the dataflow pipeline by creating a random message, the content of message does not matter, as it is only been used to trigger the pipeline. Just want to know is there a way to trigger this pipeline whenever a PubSub notification is received. Perhaps by using Apache Beam Pubsub API? Can someone give an example of such? Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look to dataflow template? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/dataflow-templates

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Guillaume, I have checked it out. Although the dataflow template is able to handle streaming job. Using beam.io.readfrompubsub would better fit my use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. You can set up your dataflow pipeline to read from a GCP pub/sub topic. You can read directly from the topic, but I recommend creating a subscription and connecting the dataflow pipeline with the subscription (why? it will prevent you from losing messages if you ever want to restart your pipeline and not miss any messages that arrive to the topic between stopping it and starting it back up again).

Heres how you do it, assuming you have already set up the GPC pub/sub topic and subscription. You'll need to remember the subscription path.

```
import apache_beam as beam
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO,
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    (pipeline
    | "Read PubSub Messages" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_topic_subscription_path)
    | "Window into fixed intervals" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.FixedWindows(5))
    | "Log the messages" >> beam.Map(lambda message: logging.info(message))
    )
```

The code above will read messages from the pub/sub topic every 5 seconds then log the message.